# Magento Overiding shopping cart prices issue

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.4

I am using magento 1.4

I am over riding the shopping cart prices by creating a script in
/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php

On the Item.php, I have this code:

```
 public function setPrice($price) //set the unit price
    {
        $qty = $this->getQty;
        $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId);
        $_product = $this->getProduct();
        $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$_product);
        foreach($childProducts as $_attribute){
            $tierPrices = $_helper->productAttribute($_attribute,$_attribute->getFormatedTierPrice());
            foreach($tierPrices as $tierPrice){
                if($qty == $tierPrice['price_qty']){
                    $price = $tierPrice['price'];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        $this->price = $price;
    }
```

Everytime I add to cart a product, it should proceed to the shopping cart page, but what happens now is I just get a blank white page.
When I also checked on my FireBug’s Console, I get a Network Error: 500 Internal Server Error.

I think the reason why that happens is my code on this line:

```
![$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$_product);][1]
```

When I try to uncomment that one, everything is okay.

I attached some images.

Can you please tell me the solution for this. Your help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks! 
[image: blank page that I got before proceeding in the shopping cart]

[image: firebug result]

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that you're not assigning your product to a variable, but either way, I've had best luck when trying to load a specific product by setting the store ID first. Here's an example.

```
$load_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->setStoreId(Mage::app()>getStore()->getId())
->load($_product->getID);
```

Save travels into the land of Magento, It's powerful, but unforgiving!

Comment: I still get the same issue. I'm still heading to the white blank page.
`$_product = $this->getProduct();
$load_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($_product->getID);
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$_product);`